# Change TemplateField Value dynamically server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, templatefield

I have a grid view in ASP.Net Application and inside that I  have TemplateField as below:

```
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Text" SortExpression="MyField">
           <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("MyField")%>
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

How can I get access to   `<%# Eval("MyField")%>` server side and change it's value? For example suppose that   `<%# Eval("MyField")%>` has a value of "`OK`", and I want to change to "`Not OK`" server side dynamically? and also **keep in mind that I dont want to use any server side control inside the TemplateField**.
This is what I tried to do, but it does not work!:

```
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.Cells(i).Text) Then
                        e.Row.Cells(i).Text = "Not OK"
                    End If
                Next
        End If
```

Comment: i posted answer try that one

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

Add Label With Templates it will be easy for you

```
<Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test Text" SortExpression="MyField">
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label id="mylabl" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Eval("MyField")%>' />
           </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
   </Columns>
```

**Server side**

```
 If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To e.Row.Cells.Count - 1
 Dim mylabl As String = _
              CType(e.Row.FindControl("mylabl"),Label).Text

                    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(mylabl ) Then
                        mylabl.Text = "Not OK"

                    End If
                Next
        End If
```

Comment: I don't want to use any server side control inside the TemplateField. This is a Custom Control that user may use Eval without using any server side control